# How can I ensure prices stay the same if I update a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use `vlookup` to pick prices from a price list in a different sheet (`sheet2`) using the codes assigned to stock items. For example, when an item code is entered in `sheet1` cell `F5`, the item price will be returned in cell `J5`. This is then multiplied by quantity in cell `J6` to get the product in cell `J7`.

The challenge is that whenever there is a change in price and the price list is adjusted, it affects both the new entries and the prices of the previous entries.

How can I make adjustments in the prices list without affecting the prices used for the previous entries?

Here is the `vlookup` formula

```
=vlookup(F5,sheet2!G2:J5000,3, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'previous entries' are calculated using formulas, i.e. your cell `J7` has the formula `J5*J6`, in turn your cell `J5` has your vlookup formula which takes a price value from `sheet2`.

Excel does not see these entries as 'previous', for Excel a cell is always 'current'. If you change a value on `sheet2`, your previous entry is updated because the formulas continue to do their job.

What you want will take a bit of manual effort, without resorting to VBA scripting.

Once you have entered an item code in `F5` and you get your product in `J7`, you'll need to

1. select `J7`
2. copy
3. paste special - values

Doing the above will remove / destroy the formula in `J7` and leave the value behind. If you want `J5` and `J6` as well, you can simply select all three in one go and paste special - values.